# Filter out values of a property in a Feature Collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I am writing a script to find where imagery from Landsat 7 and Landsat 8 overlaps within two days of each other within a certain aoi. The output for this is a feature collection with a property called `'overlap_pixel_count'`. I would like to filter the output collection to only include `'overlap_pixel_count'` values that are greater than 1,000,000.

I am having difficulty accomplishing this with the current data structure. Here is what I have thus far:

```
var pixel_overlap = l7.map(function(i){
  //get the L7 img 
  var l7_id = ee.String(i.id())
  // get the L7 image geometry to use for filtering
    var l7_geom = i.geometry()
    // get the L7 image date to use for filtering
    var l7_date = i.date()
  // pick a L7 band and get its mask
  var l7_mask = i.select(['SR_B4']).mask()
  // filter the L8 collection
  var l8collection = l8.filterBounds(l7_geom)
                       .filterDate(l7_date.advance(-2,'day'), l7_date.advance(2,'day'))
                       
  // Make a feature collection of intersecting geometries                    
  var count_feat = ee.FeatureCollection(l8collection.map(function(i){
                  //same steps as Landsat 7
                  var l8_id = ee.String(i.id())
                  var l8_geom = i.geometry()
                    var l8_date = i.date()
                  var l8_mask = i.select(['SR_B5']).mask()
                    
                  // Now find the geometric intersection of the two images
                  var intersect = l7_geom.intersection(l8_geom, 30)     
                  // multiply the l7 and l8 masks together (product > 0 means theres overlap)
                  var masks_added = l7_mask.multiply(l8_mask).gt(0)
                  // Count the number of overlapping pixels
                  var overlap_count = masks_added.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), 
                                                                geometry: intersect, 
                                                                scale: 30, 
                                                                bestEffort: true, 
                                                                maxPixels: 1e9, 
                                                                tileScale: 4});                      
      
                  //set the feature propeties to output
                  return ee.Feature(intersect).set({'ID_L7': l7_id, 'DATE_L7': l7_date, 
                                                    'ID_L8': l8_id, 'DATE_L8': l8_date,
                                                    'overlap_pixel_count': overlap_count})                 
  }))

// Return the feature collections 
  return count_feat
}).flatten() // flatten feature collections into one collection
```

Here is the sharable GEE link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/fc99c39501b877f619e4231054bc998d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value over which you want to do the filter (`'overlap_pixel_count'`) is contained inside an `ee.Dictionary` object (`reduceRegion` always returns a Dictionary). Thus, you cannot directly use a filter over a property that is a Dictionary (as you would normally do with numbers, dates or strings). The trick here is getting the desired value out of the Dictionary so it can be added as a numeric property.
In addition, I am not completely sure if you need to rename both bands (coming from l7 and l8) with the same name ('band'), but if in some cases the property obtained by the `reduceRegion` comes out from the l7_mask and others from the l8_mask, it might be a good idea to homogeneize the band names. Later, you can use that name to extract that key out of the Dictionary.

Here's the only changes I made to your script:

```
var l7_mask = i.select(['SR_B4']).mask().rename('band')

var l8_mask = i.select(['SR_B5']).mask().rename('band')

// at the end of the function
  return ee.Feature(intersect).set({
    'ID_L7': l7_id, 
    'DATE_L7': l7_date,
    'ID_L8': l8_id, 
    'DATE_L8': l8_date,
    'overlap_pixel_count': overlap_count.getNumber('band') 
})

// Then you can filter normally
var filt = pixel_overlap.filter(ee.Filter.gte('overlap_pixel_count', 1000000))
print(filt.limit(50))
```